# Unable to give permission through sudoers to a script accessing /dev/tty13

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, sudo

Here `abc` is the username and `ak.sh` is the file which I wish to get all the permissions. Have added the following line on the top of `sudoers.tmp` which I opened like `sudo visudo`:

```
abc ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/abc/ak.sh
```

ak.sh contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo cat /dev/tty13
```

When I run the script file, it asks me for password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually use `sudo` for a sudoers rule to be of use. Either:

1. Use the current sudoers rule and run `sudo /home/abc/ak.sh`
2. Use the other rule you mentioned, but with absolute path for `cat` like this:
   `abc ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/cat /dev/tty13` and run `sudo cat /dev/tty13` in the script.

Comment: I think allowing sudo cat in general to work sans password is a bit of a security issue. Better to just exempt the script, don't you think?

Comment: @LewRockwellFan since sudo does argument checking, I think either way is fine, in this case anyway.

Comment: @muru Comments don't hold format, so I'll edit my reasoning into the answer I redundantly posted. See below.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your method of password exemption works the same way as changing sudoers, you need to call the SCRIPT with sudo, not the command IN the script. Or change sudoers. In other words:

```
sudo /home/abc/ak.sh
```

is what you exempted from requiring a password, not `cat`. You still have to use `sudo` but if you did it right, you won't be required to enter a pass.

@muru

## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

Why it seems to me to be better to password exempt the script CONTAINING a cat command rather than cat itself:

```
$ ls / | grep secrets
secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt
$ # hmmm, that looks interesting . . .
$ cat /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt
cat: /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt: Permission denied
$ # Curses! My evil plans are foiled because:
$ stat /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt | grep 'Access: ('
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
$ # But wait! I'm pass exempted! So:
$ sudo cat /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt
Oh, my. Sensitive stuff is exposed to ordinary users.
```

Password exempting `sudo cat` isn't as dangerous as, for instance, password exempting `sudo echo` but it does seem to me to be a fairly bad practice.

## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

Added later to address Muru's skepticism regarding the equivalence of `sudo cat` when the password has not expired from a previous use of sudo to `sudo cat` when cat has been password exempted:

I added a rule to the beginning of my pass exemption section in /etc/sudoers like so:

```
me THIS_LOCAL_SYS=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/bin/cat, . . . [many other rules, separated by commas]
```

Then in a fresh terminal:

```
$ # Demonstrating that password is not un-expired from previous use of sudo:
$ sudo ls /root
[sudo] password for j: 
$ stat /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt|grep 'Access: ('
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
$ cat /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt 
cat: /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt: Permission denied
$ # And rightly so, but with pass exempted sudo:
$ sudo cat /secrets_root_does_not_want_to_share_.txt 
Oh, my. Sensitive stuff is exposed to ordinary users.
$
```

So, yes, they ARE equivalent, just as they should be; yes, I DO understand how sudo works - I've only edited that file a few hundred times; and yes, password exempting plain /bin/cat, instead of a script containing cat, is an unsound practice from a security perspective. Again, not the disastrous stupidity that password exempting `sudo echo` or `sudo vi` would be, but still a bad idea.

Comment: What's your sudoers rule?

Comment: I didn't redo sudoers. I simulated it by using sudo earlier in the terminal. I can't see how this would be any different. Are you saying that wouldn't work the same way? BTW, I should have grepped that stat to remove the irrelevant lines. Gonna do that now.

Comment: shrug. If you didn't actually test what you wrote, I don't care what you assume might happen.

Comment: It seems you don't really know how sudoers rules work. See for example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/178069/70524.

Comment: @muru You are actually contending the result of sudo cat with sudo exemption would be different from sudo cat when earlier password entry hasn't expired? Seriously? Wanna bet rep? I offer to bet all my rep. Even odds. Zanna can keep us honest.

Comment: @muru You could be right. Maybe I don't. Or maybe I do. Offer stands.

Comment: Sure. Whatever.

Comment: @muru OK. I'll test it the hard way. Maybe tomorrow before I do it. 4:00 a.m. here.

Comment: @muru OK, added the rule to the first of my password exemption section of  /etc/sudoers like this: me THIS_LOCAL_SYS=(ALL)NOPASSWD:/bin/cat, . . .  In a fresh terminal, works exactly the same way. I think you knew it would.

Comment: Use the actual rule under discussion here (with `/bin/cat /dev/tty13`), not some random rule you cooked up.